# Get rid of "Show Context Actions" in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, right-click

Is there any way to get rid of this thing:

[image]

And force PhpStorm to actually show the error / problem directly, after **single right-click**?

It drives me crazy that I have to click underlined item and then do something more (click context menu item or press some keyboard shortcut)? In any other software that I am used to, I see *the problem* after one click of a mouse.

Comment: Would that help if you knew that you could show context actions by placing the caret into a highlighted word and then pressing `Alt+Enter`?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I know that. Doesn't pretty much help, sorry. You are unable to press Alt+Enter without taking your hands off the mouse. Which is very counter-productive, if you have dozens or hundreds of such errors to "work out". That's why I am asking how to force PhPStorm to show list of proposed actions directly after first right-click (if this is possible at all).

Comment: If you insist on using the mouse only -- hover over the error/click to place the caret there and then click on the **light bulb icon** that will appear -- it will show the same Intentions/Context Actions/Quick Fix menu. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/intention-actions.html

Comment: OK, but the question is: can the above be turned off? Can PhpStorm show the errors / intentions directly in the context menu. Like Word, Notepad++ (with DSpellCheck plugin) and hundreds of other software does?

Comment: *"OK, but the question is: can the above be turned off?"* **1)** Remove that entry form the right-click/context menu -- YES. Just edit the menu in the settings. **2)** Show the actual intentions/quick fixes in the right click menu -- NO (could not find any options for that).

Comment: A few possible reasons for "NO": A) Each action has sub-actions (options). It requires special kind of menu handling -- when invoking an item it executes the actual action/quick fix but expanding submenu (on the same item) will show the submenu -- standard menu cannot do that. B) This menu can handle "quick search" (start typing and it will filter the entries) -- handy in some cases/when there are many items. C) Right click menu is already quite tall / has too many items, esp if you have a few extra plugins etc.

Comment: @LazyOne For me all your comments put together produces a great answer to this question. "It is not possible, what you are asking for because...", and here goes your comments. If you care to write an answer, I'll be happy to accept it and bring you some rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### NO! You cannot show the actual context actions there instead

A few possible reasons:

- Each action has sub-actions. It requires special kind of menu handling: when invoking an item it executes the actual action/quick fix but expanding submenu (on the same item; very narrow area on the right to click using the mouse) will show those extra actions/option -- standard menu cannot do that.
- This menu supports "quick search": start typing and it will filter the the intention actions. It is very handy for keyboard oriented users when there are many items there (typing 2-3 letters is faster then pressing Arrow Up / Down 4+ times.
- Right click menu is already quite tall / has too many items, especially if you have a few extra plugins that like to add their own stuff.

#### YES! You can change make this functionality a bit easier accessible

Register a mouse shortcut for this feature:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to open Settings
- Type `Show Context Actions` to the search box and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Right-click an item found in *Other* and select *Add Mouse Shortcut*
- Assign a <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Click shortcut for that item

Remove this menu item as no longer needed:

- Clear search box to reset settings to the default view
- Go to *Appearance & Behavior* → *Menus and Toolbars*
- Unfold *Editor Popup Menu* and select *ShowIntentionsGroup*
- Click minus icon in the toolbar to remove it

Now, you can access resolution list by simply pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> and clicking underlined element.

Source: [Show errors in PhpStorm with one click](https://onezeronull.com/2022/12/20/show-errors-in-phpstorm-with-one-click/)